# How to broadcast correctly subtracting 2 different matrices in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, broadcasting

I am trying to subtract two matrices of different shapes using broadcasting. However I am stuck on some point. Need simple solution of how to solve the problem.

Literally I am evaluating data on a grid (first step is subtracting). For example I have 5 grid points *grid* = (-20,-10, 0, 10, 20) and array of data of length 100.

Line: 
**u = grid.reshape((ngrid, 1)) - data** 
works perfectly fine. ngrid = 5 in this trivial example. 
Output is matrix of 5 rows and 100 columns, so each point of data is evaluated on each point of grid.

Next I want to do it for 2 grids and 2 data sets simultaneously (data is of size (2x100, e.g. 2 randn arrays). I have already succeeded in subtracting two data sets from one grid, but using two grids throws an error.

In the example below a is vertical array of the grid, length 5 points and data is array of random data of the shape (100,2).
In this case u is is tuple (2,5,100), so *u[0]* and *u[1]* has 5 rows and 100 columns, meaning that data was subtracted correctly from the grid.

Second line of the code is what I am trying to do. The error is following:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,2) (2,1,100)

**u = a - data.T[:, None]** # a is vertical grid of 5 elements. Works ok.

**u = grid_test - data.T[:, None]** # grid_test is 2 column 5 row matrix of 2 grids. Error.

What I need is kind of same line of code as above, but it should work if "*a*" contains 2 columns, e.g. two different grids. So in the end expected result is "*u*", which contains in addition to above described results another two matrices where same data (both arrays) evaluated on the second grid.

Unfortunately I cannot use any loops - only vectorization and broadcasting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have a (5,2) and (2,100).  Making the first (5,2,1) produces a (5,2,100).  That would pair one grid with one data set.  A (5,2,1) with a (5,1,2,100) produces a (5,2,2,100), with an 'outer' combination of the two grids and two sets.

Comment: Thanks to you I figured out the solution. Regards.